# Definition of good(bad) reductioness of elliptic curve by not using immersions in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $K$ be a number field, and $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$,and $\frak{p}$ be a finite place of $K$.

Then I know  the definition of good(bad) reductionness at $\frak{p}$ of $E$ by using minimal Weierstrass equation.

But I think it looks like dependent on immersion in projective place $\mathbb{P}^2$.

So I want to know is there another equivalent definition of good(bad) reductionness by not using immersion in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Also is there relation Neron model?

I have basic knowledge about  algebraic geometry such as Hartshorne, but almost don't know about elliptic curve.

Comment: What about the integral closure of $O_{K,\mathfrak{p}}[f]$ in $K(E)$ where $f$ is a function with a single pole at $O$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not enough reputation to comment)

- To define reduction, what you need is a good notion of integral model. Good/bad reduction at $p$ is then whether the fiber of the integral model at $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is still an elliptic curve.
- Minimal Weierstrass model is a good integral model for the case of elliptic curves. You are not happy with its definition because it depends on an embedding in $\mathbb{P}^2$. So one way to reframe your question is whether there is an embedding-free definition of good integral model.
- Neron model is one such embedding-free definition. It's defined by a universal property (and so by abstract nonsense it is unique if it exists), but it's not clear if exists or not. For the case of elliptic curves it does exist and coincides with the minimal Weierstrass model.

See also [this note](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/minimalmodel.pdf) from Brian Conrad.

Comment: Is it equivalent that integral model is elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. Also I added a link https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/minimalmodel.pdf which should be of interest to you as well.